# How to use recode with dplyr properly

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I am trying to recode multiple columns, using a code that has previously worked:

```
test <- tibble (
  a_test = c(7,6,5,4),
  b_test = c(7,7,5,3),
  c_test = c(7,3,7,5),
  d_test = c(7,7,7,7)
)

test %>%
  mutate(across(contains("test"), ~
                  recode(.x, "1" = "7", "2" = "6", "3" = "5", "4" = "4", "5" = "3", "6" = "2", "7" = "1")))
```

However, I now get the following error message.

```
error in mutate(): ! Problem while computing ..1 = across(...). Caused by error in across(): ! Problem while computing column a_test. Caused by error in recode(): ! unused arguments (1 = "7", 2 = "6", 3 = "5", 4 = "4", 5 = "3", 6 = "2", 7 = "1") Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred.
```

I wonder how I can solve this? Tried several things but unsuccessfully..

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine. Try with `dplyr::recode` to ensure that you are using `recode` from `dplyr`.

Comment: It does when I specify what you've mentioned. Very strange - but many thanks!!

Comment: Not strange. (: A known "issue". Some packages use the same name for functions, e.g. there is also a function named `recode` in the `car`  package. Hence, when loading `car` after `dplyr`, the `recode` from `dplyr` gets masked by the one from `car`. Ín such cases `dplyr::recode` ensures that you get the one from dplyr.